# Why does Redis scan return keys which belong to another node

Tags: redis, redis-cli

When I scan the Redis using below command:

```
redis-cli -h <redis_master_ip> -p 6379  --scan --pattern '*'
```

it returns keys which belong to this node, but it also returns many keys which belong to another redis node. Therefore if I run below command:

```
redis-cli -h <redis_master_ip> -p 6379 object freq <some_keys_from_scan>
```

I get error like `Error: MOVED 90 <another_redis_master_ip>:6379`

Due to the same reason, I get the same error when running:

```
redis-cli -h <redis_master_ip> -p 6379 --hotkeys
```

Note both the <redis_master_ip> and <another_redis_master_ip> are a part of redis cluster.

The document https://redis.io/commands/scan defines scan as: "iterates the set of keys in the currently selected Redis database". My understanding is it should only scan the keys belong to the current node. my redis cluster is 6.0.10.

Does anybody know why executing `scan` return the keys of another node? I am only interested in getting the keys of this node.

I see another link mentioned the same issue but no solution yet: https://github.com/redis/redis/issues/4810

Comment: This is caused due to the encoding of the key name.